# Port used for ASP.NET application

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net, port

I am setting up a Windows Server 2008 R2 on a VPS.

I have ASP.NET 4.0 apps running on IIS (Push notification services for Windows phone 7).

My question is, what port should I use for the app connection? Does it matter, or should I use 80 as it's already open? The traffic needs to flow in and out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm puzzled by this question. What do you mean exactly by "what port should I use"?

You said it's an ASP.NET application and it's running on IIS. So what would it need other than the standard 80 or 443 ports?

If you're talking about some application-specific connection, then only you know... but if it's a web site, or a web service, or anything "web"-related, then unless you have some specific reason to have it not listening on port 80/443, why should you change it?

Comment: Thank you. Thats the answer I was after. Its clear im a newbie at this! :-)